# How to use a gauge chart in Google Sheets programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, embedded-resource, gauge

I would like to add a "Gauge chart" in Google sheets programmatically. This is an example that I found on the internet but it is coded to display the chart on a webpage. I will, however, try to work off of that example code. But, any help is appreciated. Here's the example
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to create "Gauge chart" to the Spreadsheet.
- You need a sample script for achieving this with Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, as a test case, please set `sample` and `50` to the cells of "A1" and "B1", respectively.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.GAUGE)
    .addRange(sheet.getRange('A1:B1'))
    .setPosition(3, 1, 0, 0)
    .setOption('height', 300)
    .setOption('width', 300)
    .setOption('title', 'Sample chart')
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [newChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#newChart())
- [insertChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart)
- [Class EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Perfect! I am pretty sure that is what I want but is this manipulative? Can you add code where you are able to change the position of the dial according to a value, please?

Comment: @Jrules80 Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your replying, when you want to change the dial of the gauge chart, how about modifying the value? In above case, when you modify `50` of the cell "B1", the dial is changed. But unfortunately, the dial is changed soon. It seems that this is the specification. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: Hello, Tanaike - At this tiime, I do not have to pursue this approach. But, when the need comes, I will check back. I am accepting your solution. Thank you for your support.